# #include <cmath>

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmath

What is wrong with the code snippet below that VS2010 wouldn't compile it?

```
int m = sqrt( n );
```

( I am trying to ascertain whether an integer is prime... )

Comment: There is not enough information to decide why the code you've shown wouldn't compile.  What error message do you get?

Comment: I get: error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Comment: it sounds like `n` is the wrong type.  Check out @Erik's answer.

Comment: Erik's answer works. Instead of `int m = sqrt( n );` I should use `long double m = sqrt(static_cast<long double>(n));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a specific floating point type to `sqrt` - there's no integer overload. Use e.g:

```
long double m = sqrt(static_cast<long double>(n));
```

As you include `cmath` not `math.h` I'm assuming you want c++. For C, you'll need to use e.g:

```
double m = sqrt((double) n);
```

The error you get simply means that the compiler cannot automatically select a `sqrt` function for you - the integer you pass needs to be converted to a floating point type, and the compiler doesn't know which floating point type and `sqrt` function it should select.